# excenção de reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx

olá, estou tentando fazer um aplicação que rode uma musica infinitamente, porém quando o usuário clicar num botão a musica pare ,
esse é o meu código

```
public void tocar() { 
 relogio = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {

      clip.play();
  }),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10))
   );
   relogio.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
   relogio.play();
}
```

aqui é o botão onde supostamente deveria parar a timeline relogio

```
  public void eventoMusica(ActionEvent evento){
    if (gettexto().equals("desligar")){
        clip.stop();
        relogio.stop();
        botaoEvento.setText("ligar");
    }
    else{
        tocar();
        botaoEvento.setText("desligar");
    }
}
```

porém é exatamente no "relogio.stop()" que capturo essa exceção ,como resolvo isso ?

Comment: Qual o tipo da variável clip? MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

Criei um exemplo a partir do código disponibilizado e funcionou. Algumas coisas que podem ter influenciado:

1. Utilizei o MediaPlayer do javafx para tocar a música. A pergunta não diz qual classe está sendo utilizada para tocar a música, pelo nome da variável, parece ter sido a classe javax.sound.sampled.Clip.
2. A pergunta não diz como esses métodos estão sendo chamados, no meu caso, fiz a implementação no onMouseClicked do botão.
3. Utilizei o java8.
4. Utilizei um arquivo .mp3.

Segue código:

```
String path = "music.mp3";
File file = new File(path);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(file.toURI().toString()));
Timeline relogio = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> mediaPlayer.play()), 
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10)));

relogio.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
relogio.play();

Button button = new Button("desligar");
button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (button.getText().equals("desligar")){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        relogio.stop();
        button.setText("ligar");
    }
    else{
        mediaPlayer.play();
        relogio.play();
        button.setText("desligar");
    }
});

Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().add(button);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,400);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```